# Default Constraint with Column name of table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
CREATE TABLE #temp
(FName    VARCHAR(10),
 LName    VARCHAR(10),
 FullName VARCHAR(21) DEFAULT(FName+' '+LName)
);
```

When I try the above statement I am getting the following error. Is there any workaround available for this?

> Msg 128, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   The name "FName" is not permitted in this context. Valid expressions are constants, constant expressions, and (in some contexts) variables. Column names are not permitted.

Comment: Either you want `FullName` to always be `FName + ' ' + LName`, then make it a computed column. Or you only want to set an initial value, then use a before-insert trigger.

Comment: Thanks for providing workaround.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't need to edit it you can use a calculated column

```
CREATE TABLE #temp
(FName    VARCHAR(10),
 LName    VARCHAR(10),
 FullName AS (FName+' '+LName)
);
```